# Get text that lies after pattern without class or id

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, html-agility-pack

I am using the [HtmlAgiityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

It is an excellent tool for parsing data, however every instance I have used it, I have always had either a class or id to aim at, i.e. -

```
string example = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='target']").InnerText.Trim();
```

However I have come across a piece of text that isn't nested in any particular pattern with a class or id I can aim at. E.g. -

```
<p>Example Header</p>: This is the text I want!<br>
```

However the example given does always following the same patter i.e. the text will always be after `</p>:` and before `<br>`.

I can extract the text using a regular expression however would prefer to use the agility pack as the rest of the code follows suit. Is there a means of doing this using the pack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath works for me :

```
var html = @"<div class=""target"">
<p>Example Header</p>: This is the text I want!<br>
</div>";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();

doc.LoadHtml(html);
var result = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/div[@class='target']/text()[(normalize-space())]").OuterHtml;
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

- `/text()` select all text nodes that is direct child of the `<div>`
- `[(normalize-space())]` exclude all text nodes those contain only white
  spaces (there are 2 new lines excluded from this html sample : one before `<p>` and the other after `<br>`)

Result :
[image]

**UPDATE I :**

All element must have a parent, like `<div>` in above example. Or if it is the root node you're talking about, the same approach should still work. The key is to use `/text()` XPath to get text node :

```
var html = @"<p>Example Header</p>: This is the text I want!<br>";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var result = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/text()[(normalize-space())]").OuterHtml;
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**UPDATE II :**

Ok, so you want to select text node after `<p>` element and before `<br>` element. You can use this XPath then :

```
var result = 
        doc.DocumentNode
           .SelectSingleNode("/text()[following-sibling::br and preceding-sibling::p]")
           .OuterHtml;
```

Comment: perhaps I was unclear however the '/div[@class='target']' was an example of when I can get the text, the second example has no div, class OR id attached to it. Hence my problem.

Comment: check my update. All element must have criteria to enable you create a query to select it. So what is the criteria for this text element, is it simply text element that contain text "*This is the text I want!*"? If it is so, you can use this XPath : `/text()[contains(., 'This is the text I want!')]`

Comment: Ok, i have read your update, however the text is always changing that I want to acquire, so the method of contains won't work? The criteria would be it si the text that always follows '</p>' and before '<br>'

Comment: I see. Apparently you already stated that in question (sorry missed that part). Check **Update II** section.

Comment: That's the one! Spot on bud.